# Select element by id from the dom, using Java., the element tag is not visible on the inspect

Tags: javascript, java, automation, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

[image: 1]

I tried the below code but the button wasn't selected.

```
WebElement rvbtn = driver.findElement(By.name("rv"));
rvbtn.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to select the radio button, you should use the following code :

```
WebElement rvbtn = driver.findElement(By.name("inputValue"));
rvbtn.click();
```

You used the **value** attribute instead of the **name** attribute inside your **By.name** selector.